# Slovak eVRC smart card (AID)

Tags: smartcard, apdu

Does anyone know from where can I get the AID of Slovak eVRC smart card?
Can I read it from the card?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eVRC applications based on EU directive 2003/127/EC seem to use the AID `A0000004564556522D3031`. I assume this would also be the case for Slovakia.

Comment: This works for Slovakia. Do you know how can I get the length of EF?

Comment: No, but the protocol specification is part of the EU directive, so you can possibly look that up there.

Comment: This might help https://gist.github.com/alhafoudh/1fed59c4cacf38a997b8f718fbf70b89